# Can I join a faction and later leave and start my own faction?

Tags: spaz2

The game is giving me the task to join a faction.

I saw in some places that starting my own faction is much better than joining one.

Is it possible to join a faction and later, leave and start my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can join a faction now and later on in the story you will get the option you start your own.

Comment: That just happened. The first step is join a faction, after a few other events, I get to start my own faction. Thanks.